# How to write a text file of local maximum from another text file?

Tags: python, text, max

I have a text file with two columns. I want to find the local maximum of the first column. I have no problem with this step. After that i want to write complete rows of those local maximum in a new text file. I have problem in this step. The priblem in my code is related to the line "for line in range peaks:". peaks here are the indexes of those rows which contain local maximum.

```
f = open ('rr.txt', 'r')
data = f.readlines()
a = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in data]
a = np.array(a)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(a, height=0)

with open('peaks.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in range peaks:
        f.write(line)
```

input:

```
0 11
3 11
2 12
1 13
4 20
2 21
```

Peaks are:

```
array([1,4])
```

and
a[peaks]= 3 ,4

and desired output:

```
3 11
4 20
```

Comment: Having any error?

Comment: Yes there is a syntax error. for line in range peaks:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `range` is a built-in function, so you have to use it like `range(10)` or `range(0,10, 1)`.

Comment: But here how can I make a loop through the indexes ? "peaks" gives me those indexes.

Comment: If `peaks` have the indexes then just loop through `peaks` and index at `a`, no?

Comment: My question is how to make a loop through peaks. peaks is like this: [2 , 5]. these numbers are the number of rows which I need. So I need to write the whole second and fifth rows of my first file in a new text file.

Comment: Can you show small sample input, and the desired output? In the question please.